# Why doesn't visual studio find soundio.h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cmake

I've been working with visual studio 19 and cmake. The initial objective is to link spdlog and libsoundio libraries to my project, to achieve it the following CMakeFile was created to compile my project.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(APPNAME DrumHero)
project($APPNAME)

#C++ version
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(SOURCES src/drumhero.cpp)
set(HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/drumhero.h)

set(DEPENDENCIES_LIBS spdlogd libsoundio)

link_directories("C:/Program\ Files/libsoundio/lib" "C:/Program\ Files/spdlog/lib") 
include_directories("C:/Program\ Files/libsoundio/include" "C:/Program\ Files/spdlog/include")

add_executable (${APPNAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(${APPNAME} 
                          PUBLIC ${DEPENDENCIES_LIBS})

set_target_properties(${APPNAME} PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}")
```

All libraries are installed and located in Program Files.

I copied the [example program from libsoundio](http://libsound.io/), but visual studio is showing some errors related to libsoundio, it seems that the library is not found by visualstudio, like the errors shown in the image below:

[image]

What it's most strange is that the code compiles, but when the .exe is executed the following message is shown:

[image]

Translation:
The execution of the code could not continue because libsoundio.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

Why is libsoundio not found?

Comment: "Why is libsoundio not found?" - This is because your library is can be found neither in the directory near the executable nor in directories pointer by `PATH` environment variable. The fact that the library has been found when **build** the executable has no relation to the searching the library at **runtime**. This is one of the facts you should be aware of when programming on Windows.

Comment: Please note, that Stack Overflow discourages using *images* for error messages or other logs which could be represented as *text*. Instead, this information should be posted as **text**. See [ask].

Comment: Ok I will replace the images by texts.
Now, about you first comment @Tsyvarev, what confuses me is that I pointed to the location of the libraries in my CMakeFile, Isn't that enough to visual studio and windws find it?

Comment: Yes, specifying the location of the library for building the executable is not enough when find this library at runtime. Just google for "windows find dll" or similar words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code has sucessfully compiled, you have two options: Either copy the `libsoundio.dll` in the same folder as your `.exe`, or else, copy that DLL into a typical Windows path for DLLs, for example, `C:\Windows\System32`.

The first method should be easier if you want to deploy your application to another computer. That is the reason why Software for Windows is distributed as Installers, which create a folder in your machine and copy multiple files, sometimes DLLs, in the same path as the `.EXE`